# service async update value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a dialog controller:

```
.controller('loadingDialogCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog, $rootScope, loadingDialog) {
    $scope.loadingDialog = loadingDialog;
});
```

In my other controller i show this dialog controller and manipulate with it by `LoadingDialogService`:

```
.controller('myCtr', function($scope, $mdDialog, loadingDialog) {
   $mdDialog.show({
       controller: 'loadingDialogCtrl',
       templateUrl: 'tmpl/loadingDialog.tmpl.html'
   });
   loadingDialog.status = "Formatting...";

})
```

`LoadingDialog` service:

```
angular.module('LoadingDialogService', []).service('loadingDialog', function ($mdDialog) {
    this.progress = 0;
    this.status = "Loading data from board...";
    this.additionalStatus = "";
    this.mode = "determinate";

    return {
        progress: this.progress,
        status: this.status,
        additionalStatus: this.additionalStatus,
        mode: this.mode
    }
});
```

This works fine. But for example if i change service value in async function, my dialog view doesn't update:

```
//progress bar inside dialog have changed
loadingDialog.progress = 55;
setTimeout(function () {
    //progress bar inside dialog didn't change
    loadingDialog.progress = 55;
}, 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `loadingDialogCtrl` instead of

```
$scope.loadingDialog = loadingDialog;
```

you should use

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return loadingDialog;
}, function(loadingDialogValue) {
    $scope.loadingDialog = loadingDialogValue;
}, true);
```

OR (more elegant solution)

```
$scope.getLoadingDialog = function() {
    return loadingDialog;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout()` is outside angular's digest cycle, so the view value won't update. Use `$timeout()` instead. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Comment: value is changed 100% - because console.log(loadingDialog.progress)  prints progress

Comment: The value changes - but the digest cycle doesn't run, which means the value in your HTML won't update. Using $timeout should fix it, unless there's another problem. Can you add your dialog view to your post?

Comment: @Arti $timeout is the correct solution. Consider providing [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if it doesn't work for some reason. It is not clear how `loadingDialog` is used in your case.